# Mi .draw no funciona cuando le mando un valor y una columna para que haga el match y me traiga los resultados, (No hace Nada)

Tags: datatables, bootstrap

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando escriba texto en un textfield mio que tengo que no es el que trae por defecto boostrap me haga una búsqueda por una columna en especifico pero simplemente no hace nada y se queda la tabla sin ningún cambio:

Código Actual

```
 $('#txtPlataformGeneral').keyup(function () {
        table.destroy();
        table.columns(5).search("^" + $(this).val() + "$", true, false).draw();
        $('#txtServerGeneral').val("");
        $('#txtAppGeneral').val("");
        if ($('#txtPlataformGeneral').val() == "") {
            $(".ImgFilters").addClass("hidden");
            table.search('').columns().search('').draw();
        } else {
            $(".ImgFilters").removeClass("hidden");
        }
    })
```

Inclusive intente con `table.destroy();` antes del `.draw`, todo lo demás de la función si lo hace salvo la búsqueda del draw y de hecho antes si lo hacia pero como era un proyecto que se fue posponiendo lo retome y note que eso dejo de funcionar.